# magento transactional e-mail don't work after upgrade

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.6

My Magento shop doesn't send e-mails after upgrading 1.4.1 to 1.6.2. We changed the location of the magento files from /magento-1.4 to the root during the upgrade.

The server hasn't changed and other installations on the same server are able to send magento mails.

Mail configuration hasn't changed since the previous installation. I've checked them and they all seem fine.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can PHP send mail on the server?

Comment: yes php can send mail.. through mail('my@email.com','mysubject','mycontent'); and it always worked on the same server running magento 1.4.1

Comment: Is there a problem with sending transactional emails only? Are new registration emails or contact form working?

Comment: Tim, these aren't working either.. I've made a test mail file which doesn't work either:

<?php
try {
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename; 
Mage::app('');
$orderId = 5032;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$order->setCustomerEmail('my@email.com');
$order->setCustomerIsGuest(1);

    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
    echo "Verstuurd en gelukt\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>